# Does Google Maps Support European Languages?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, localization

I tried to display a map by using various languages in the url in the scrip tag:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=this-is-me&language=fr
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=this-is-me&language=de
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=this-is-me&language=es
```

The map names are shown both in English and the local language. With some exceptions e.g. Ivory Coast is only in local language: Cote d'ivoire.

One would expect the map to be in the language requested. This is never the case in the languages I tested. Am I doing something wrong or is the actual translation totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that anything will be translated.
At least the interface-elements(e.g. maptype-controls) should be translated.

Basically all 3 languages are supported ([list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For many cultures though trying to read a map in a different language is next to impossible. If you were to travel from Varsovie, Pologne to Vienne, Autriche; would you guess that it is taking you from Warsaw, Poland to Vienna in Austria (which incidentally they call Wien in Osterreich)? This may definitely prevent using the map for many applications targeted to non English speakers.

Comment: This may apply to the map-labels, but usually resonses from the services(e.g. directions) will be  translated